# Change Time zone and date format

Tags: java, android

I get from the server is like  `2017-01-24T16:16:30.690Z.`

This date is in GMT time zone.

I want to convert this time into `GMT+6` time zone as well as time format.

My expected result is: `24 January 2017 22:16`

Comment: So it sounds like you should be using a `SimpleDateFormat` with an appropriate format and time zone... have you tried anything yet? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

See above comments. If you apply those, try:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
    sdf.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date date = sdf.parse("2017-01-24T16:16:30.690Z", new ParsePosition(0));
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+06:00"));
    sdf.applyPattern("d MMMM yyyy HH:mm");
    String formatted = sdf.format(date);
```

Worked for me.